# Event .click () on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several click event made on this way:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        //do samething...
    });

    $('#button2').click(function () {
        //do samething...
    });
    .....
});
```

In different part of my application, I want to turn-off the clicks, and later turn-on them again:

I can turn off the click invoking this function:

```js
function keysLock() {
    $('#button1').off('click');
};
```

Now I can't restore the click function. I tried with something like

```
$('#button1').on('click')
```

(and a lot of similar stuff) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, `.off()` doesn't turn it off in the sense of flicking a light switch, it *removes* the handler. If you bind named functions then you can rebind them with `$("#button1").click(namedFunction)`, or you can update the handler to have a flag as to whether it is currently active, and then in `keysLock()` just set that flag to false. @pmahomme - `.click()` isn't deprecated. And it's just a shortcut to `.on()` - it's not the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add an alternative solution based on your comments, you can use a variable to enable/disable the events and you don't have to remove the handlers then, something like that:

```
$(function () {
  var someSpecificCondition = false;

  function doThisStuffOnClick () {
    if (someSpecificCondition) {
      return;
    }
    // do something
  }

  $('#button1, #button2').click(doThisStuffOnClick);    
});
```

Comment: Okay, edited as I missed that they are the same. Using `off` and custom classes seems to be overkill.

Comment: I think that OP cannot get a better answer than those two without showing more code + insight in what he's doing. I even think it might be an *XY Problem*.

Answer (score 3):

...`.on()` ... `.off()` so yeah

Aassign a click custom function like:

```
function doThisStuffOnClick () {
  // do someshitng
}
```

than use he `.on()` method:

```
$("#button1").on("click", doThisStuffOnClick);
```

than to turn it OFF:

```
$("#button1").off("click");
```

than to turn it back ON again

```
$("#button1").on("click", doThisStuffOnClick);
```

---

Read always more here: [`.off()`<sup>jQuery Docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: You should mention namespacing as it may be a good idea to use them too.

Comment: @IstvánUjj-Mészáros yep thx but. Not now. Totally no need to `click:fick`. Let's just keep this for a later time.

Comment: It is always a good idea in my opinion when you are using `off` just to avoid future issues, as `off` will remove all `click` handlers, not just the one with `doThisStuffOnClick`.

Comment: @IstvánUjj-Mészáros the more you're mentioning that, the more I agree with you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, is there no way to achieve this without specify the function for every button? I have lot of buttons!! I would like to make this using class and stop all the clicks event.

Comment: @mario (U'W!) than you're clearly doing something wrong. Can't you find some commons use-click-case to bind those clicks over some class selector? What I mean is that tha `//do samething...` in your Q can't help me to help you further...

Comment: I have about 50 buttons. Every button does specific stuff. If a certain condition is true, I want to disable all the buttons except for 2 of these. Sure i am doing something wrong :D I also tried adding and removing a new class "block": same thing, the .off() it works, but later i can't restore the click function

Comment: @mario That's what I'm saying! Than use CLASS like `$(".btn").not("#btn68, #btn104").off("click");` http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: //do something it means call other js function, it could happen that inside of them i call the function keysLock()

Comment: dear @mario what I mean is that there's too less information in your question for me to figure out what's your *main* issue