# How to disable a click and re enable it later on with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is triggered by a click. I want after I click it, disabling the click. So I made this

```
$('.item-blog').on('click', function(){

    $('.item-blog').off('click');

});
```

and It's working perfectly.

But later on, at the end of all the events, within the last function, when I have resetted all the stuff and I have run all the code, I want to be able to re click the first function in order to fire the same events again. So I put this within the last function that resets everything.

```
$('.item-blog').on('click');
```

But it is not working at all.

I even tried bind and unbind but every time I want to re enable the click, it is never working.

Some help?

Thank you very much

Comment: The `.off()` method doesn't turn the handler off in the sense of turning off a light switch, it *removes* the handler in the sense of pulling out the lightbulb and all of its associated wiring.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459153/alternative-to-jquerys-toggle-method-that-supports-eventdata

Comment: Here's another duplicate with an answer that uses a flag rather than adding and removing the handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906793/event-click-on-and-off

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `on` and `off` as below to toggle the click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function toggleClick(on) {

   if(on) {
      $('.item-blog').on('click', function(){
         console.log('clicked');
         toggleClick(false);

      });

   } else {
      $('.item-blog').off('click');
   }

}

toggleClick(true);

$('.item-blog-reset').on('click', function(){
    console.log('Reset done');
    toggleClick(true);

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click" class="item-blog" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" class="item-blog-reset" />
```

Comment: `.bind` and `.unbind` are deprecated as of jQuery 3.0. So it ain't a long term solution.

Comment: Thanks, updated with `on` and `off`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the class instead... And add a temporary one.
;)

```
$(document).on('click','.item-blog', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("item-blog").addClass("item-blog-disabled");
});
```

Then, later, you will only have to re-add the class using the `item-blog-disabled` class.
like:

```
$(document).find('.item-blog-disabled').removeClass("item-blog-disabled").addClass("item-blog");
```

So now, the handler is binded to the `document` which delegates for `.item-blog` it has.

Giving you the opportunity to remove/add the handler on those elements using a simple class.

Comment: I know... I just edited.

Comment: You're right... Better now ? ;)